# remove a cell from my table from a button within

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

Im having trouble removing the cell from the table i tried to create some protocols but it didnt work since im new to this language i can't think of many solutions to this.

```
    extension CustomTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                    numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return sneakers.count + 1
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         
         
         if indexPath.row == sneakers.count {
             guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OrderSummaryView") as? OrderSummaryView else {
                 print("I'll never print")
                 return OrderSummaryView()
             }

             return cell
         }

         let product = sneakers[indexPath.row]

         guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell") as? ExampleCell else {
             print("I'll never print")
             return ExampleCell()
         }

         print("Utilize cells")
         cell.configure(product: product)
         return cell
     }

  
}
```

this is how im using my table cells

```
import UIKit



   final class ExampleCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    private let productImageView: UIImageView = .init(frame: .zero)
    private let categoryLabel: UILabel = .init(frame: .zero)
    private let nameLabel: UILabel = .init(frame: .zero)
    private let priceLabel: UILabel = .init(frame: .zero)
    private let sizeLabel: UILabel = .init(frame: .zero)
    private let colorLabel: UILabel = .init(frame: .zero)
    
    private let removeButton = UIButton()
    // Replace "transparent" with the name of your transparent image
    private let clearImage = UIImage(named: "Image-1")
   let qtyButton = UIButton()
    private let arrowQty = UIImage(named: "Arrow_Qty")
    private let wishButton = UIButton()

    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default,reuseIdentifier: "ExampleCell")
        
        print("New cell has been create")
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()

    }
    
    // Init with coder is when the cell is instaciated via storyboard/XIB
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(product: Product) {
        productImageView.image = product.image
        categoryLabel.text = product.category
        nameLabel.text = product.name
        priceLabel.text = "\(product.price)€"
        sizeLabel.text = "Size: \(product.size)"
        colorLabel.text = "Color: \(product.color)"
    }

    
    private func setupUI() {
        selectionStyle = .none
        
        let array = [productImageView,
                     categoryLabel,
                     nameLabel,
                     priceLabel,
                     sizeLabel,
                     colorLabel,
                     removeButton,
                     qtyButton,
                     wishButton]
        
        array.forEach { view in
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            addSubview(view)
        }
        
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        
        categoryLabel.font = FontStyle.uiS.baseUIFont
        categoryLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_400")
        
        nameLabel.font = FontStyle.displayMBold.baseUIFont
        nameLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700")
        
        priceLabel.font = FontStyle.uiS.baseUIFont
        priceLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700")
        
        sizeLabel.font = FontStyle.uiXS.baseUIFont
        sizeLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700")
        
        colorLabel.font = FontStyle.uiXS.baseUIFont
        colorLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700")
        
        removeButton.setImage(clearImage, for: .normal)
        
        qtyButton.setTitle("Qty:1   ", for: .normal)
        qtyButton.setImage(arrowQty, for: .normal)
        qtyButton.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        qtyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        qtyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_White")
        qtyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700"), for: .normal)
        qtyButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        qtyButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "GreyScale_400")?.cgColor
        qtyButton.titleLabel?.font = FontStyle.uiM.baseUIFont
        
        wishButton.setTitle("Move to wishlist", for: .normal)
        wishButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(named: "GreyScale_700"), for: .normal)
        wishButton.titleLabel?.font = FontStyle.uiM.baseUIFont
        //underline wishButton
        let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Move to wishlist", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        wishButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, for: .normal)
    }
    
    private func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 242),
            
            productImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            productImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            productImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 106),
            productImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 114),
            
            categoryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 18),
            categoryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            categoryLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 29),
            categoryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14),
            
            nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: categoryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            nameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 159),
            nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 24),
            
            priceLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            priceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            priceLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56),
            priceLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14),
            
            sizeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            sizeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 32),
            sizeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 46),
            sizeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            colorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            colorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sizeLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            colorLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62),
            colorLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            removeButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            removeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            removeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12),
            
            qtyButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: productImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            qtyButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 32),
            qtyButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 106),
            qtyButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20),
            qtyButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64),
           
            wishButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 56),
            wishButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: qtyButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 128),
            wishButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 116),
            wishButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 16),
        ])
    }
}
```

this is where i declared the stuff thats inside the cells with this i want the remove button to remove the cell from the table and the view can u guys help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a button action in your cell, then add a **closure** so your cell can tell the table view controller that the button was tapped.

So, in `ExampleCell` ...

Add a closure:

```
final class ExampleCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // closure
    var removeMe: ((ExampleCell) -> ())?
```

also in `ExampleCell` - after you've "setup the UI", add an action for your button:

```
    removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

the selector func can look like this:

```
@objc func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("Tapped remove button")

    // call the closure
    removeMe?(self)
}
```

Now, in your controller, when you dequeue the cell in `cellForRowAt`, set the closure:

```
    let product = sneakers[indexPath.row]

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell") as? ExampleCell else {
        print("I'll never print")
        return ExampleCell()
    }

    print("Utilize cells")
    cell.configure(product: product)
    
    // configure the closure
    cell.removeMe = { [weak self] aCell in
        guard let self = self,
              let idxPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: aCell)
        else { return }
        
        print("Update data and remove cell from table view...")
        self.sneakers.remove(at: idxPath.row)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [idxPath], with: .automatic)
    }
    
    return cell
```

As a side note -- don't use `guard let ...` when dequeuing a cell:

```
    // don't do it like this
    //guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell") as? ExampleCell else {
    //  print("I'll never print")
    //  return ExampleCell()
    //}

    // dequeue the cell like this
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExampleCell", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCell
```

If you have incorrectly registered your table view cells, you ***want*** the app to crash so you can fix the issue.